# Android : Branch SDK Crash Issue in production build

Tags: android, crash, branch.io

I am using Branch SDK in my application (latest version of Android Branch SDK (v4.3.2))
Since last update I am facing class not found issue in production release. But in development it works without any issues. Here is the crash log from firebase.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to instantiate receiver io.branch.referral.InstallListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.branch.referral.InstallListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/gman.vedicastro-dnsDZX6uCyAilVBlCp8zjQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/gman.vedicastro-dnsDZX6uCyAilVBlCp8zjQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "io.branch.referral.InstallListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/gman.vedicastro-dnsDZX6uCyAilVBlCp8zjQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/gman.vedicastro-dnsDZX6uCyAilVBlCp8zjQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
```

As per the document from branch, I have removed this code from Android Manifest file

```
<receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Any idea why this issue happened?

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: you may need to enable the multidex

Comment: @Fahad Alotaibi, Thanks for the idea, But I already enabled multidex.

Comment: did you create this class io.branch.referral.InstallListener?

Comment: @Fahad Alotaibi, No I didn't create that. it's Branch SDK task. but now issue fixed. please check my post right below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a cache issue particularly when multidex builds are involved. I did following steps and it solves the problem -

1. Disabling instant run on Android Studio.
2. Running the following command  ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew cleanbuildcache (note syntax is slightly different on Windows).
3. Finally relaunch Android Studio via File -> Invalidate caches / restart ...

Also, please double check the latest Android SDK (v4.3.2) documentation and confirm that you have added all the necessary command/code in all of the files. Here's the link to the latest doc - https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/

I hope this helps to someone.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for notifying us.

Our docs are currently all updated. On the bottom of each doc page, we notify on the last updated date for the docs.